# Rosmake: avoid rebuilding dependencies

Tags: rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm currently working on a ROS package which has many dependencies.
Every time I make a change to package and want to recompile it, I run

```
$ rosmake `package-name`
```

which actually builds the package and **all** of its dependencies, even if they have already been built during some previous compilation and their sources did not change.

Not being familiar with **rosmake**, I don't know whether this is how it works or I am missing something.
Is there a way to tell **rosmake** to *skip* dependencies whose binaries already exist?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57024/rosmake:-avoid-rebuilding-dependencies/) by [kid-a](https://answers.ros.org/users/4350/kid-a/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes:

```
roscd packagename
make
```

That's basically what rosmake does for all packages in the dependency tree.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kid-a](https://answers.ros.org/users/4350/kid-a/) on 2013-03-04**:
Right. Reading carefully http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosmake: "If you really just want to build a package, and you know that its dependencies are up-to-date, you just type make in that package's top-level directory".

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2013-03-04**:
Does this skip dependencies whose binaries already exist, or skip all dependencies that are up-to-date, or skip all dependencies? Seems like you could get into trouble by using make on its own.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-03-04**:
It skips all dependencies. If in doubt, run rosmake.

**Comment by [kleinsplash](https://answers.ros.org/users/5014/kleinsplash/) on 2014-01-21**:
So - I find that running rosmake packagename --pre-clean helps sometimes when there have been errors, what would be nice is being able to skip certain dependencies that you know compile (and take the longest) and still use --pre-clean..

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2014-01-21**:
You can run `make clean` in whatever directories you think appropriate, leaving the others alone.